# c++ casting char* to object?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

Is it possible in C++ to convert an array of chars to an object like so:

```
char* bytes = some bytes...
MyObject obj = (MyObject)(bytes);
```

?
How do I have to define the cast operator?
thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to define a constructor for MyObject:

```
class MyObject {
public:
  explicit MyObject(const char* bytes);
  ...
};

MyObject::MyObject(const char* bytes) {
  // do whatever you want to initialize "MyObject" from the byte string
}
```

and then you can use it:

```
char* bytes = some bytes...
MyObject obj = MyObject(bytes);  // this will work
MyObject obj(bytes);             // so will this
```

Comment: You can also do `MyObject obj = bytes;`. I'd suggest using the `explicit` keyword on the constructor to prevent that, it can avoid some surprising bugs.

Comment: If you go this way, don't forget the rule of three (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). You should add a destructor and copy assignment operator in there as well.

Comment: Yeah, `explicit` is a very good idea for single-parameter constructors.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Note that the constructor of `std::string` is not `explicit` and does what we expect.

Answer (score 4):

I can see two possibilities here. If you have data that you know represents the target type, you can use a `reinterpret_cast` to get them treated as an object of that type:

```
MyObject *obj = reinterpret_cast<MyObject *>(bytes);
```

If you want to create an object of the specified type *in* the designated memory, you use the `placement new` operator to construct an object at the specified address:

```
char *bytes = whatever;

MyObject *obj = new(bytes) MyObject;
```

When you're finished using the object, you don't `delete` it, you directly invoke the dtor:

```
obj->~MyObject();
```

Note that for this to work, you need to ensure that (if nothing else) `bytes` points to data that's aligned correctly for the destination type.

Comment: Yes. This will construct a new object at that location. If you have an already constructed object there (perhaps the pointer was already casted from `MyObject *` and you are just casting it back now?) then larsmans' answer is the way to go.

Comment: @T.E.D: No, not really. As noted in my edited answer, if you know what's there really represents an object of the specified type, you want to use a `reinterpret_cast`, not a `static_cast`.

Comment: @Jerry: I just spotted the error in my answer myself and corrected it.

Comment: Right. That could be the case either because you happen to know that some other code already constructed an object there, or because it is a POD object.

Comment: @T.E.D.: "because it is a POD object" doesn't really mean/help much. It still falls pretty much under the first provision -- it'll only *be* a POD object because some other code already constructed it there.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - Really? I thought PODs didn't have to be constructed.

Comment: Pretty sure this is formally UB & the only defined way is to allocate a `T` & `memcpy` to it. @T.E.D. Even if _trivially copyable_ types - the superset of PODs guaranteed to be copyable to array of `char` & back & retain the same value - don't in reality emit code when allocated, the Standard still demands they have a real lifetime. This presumably means the compiler must see code that says 'Create a `struct T` in this piece of memory', otherwise all bets are off & UB means it can emit unsafe code or optimise the attempt away. That most compilers allow arbitrary casting doesn't make it defined

Answer (score 3):

If the bytestring actually represents a valid object of type `MyObject`, you can get a `MyObject*` with

```
reinterpret_cast<MyObject *>(bytes)
```

(This is very unlikely to work though, unless the `char*` is the result of casting a pointer to a properly constructed `MyObject`.)

Comment: +1, but the part in parentheses is important enough that the parentheses should be removed.

Comment: Isn't this UB? Doesn't it violate the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod `char*` is exempt from that rule, so only if another non-`char*`, non-`MyObject*` pointer/reference also references `bytes`.

Comment: Casting **to** `char *` & dereferencing the result is exempt from aliasing. There's no allowance for the opposite. But as long as the pointers aren't dereferenced in the same scope - which surely there's no reason to do - then aliasing doesn't even enter into the equation. This is the same as/follows from the rule allowing 'round trip' casting of pointers & ensuring casting `A *` => `B *` => `A *` preserves the same `A *` on both sides. If one couldn't even cast the _addresses_ of objects without aliasing, this wouldn't be possible. Aliasing only refers to _dereferenced_ pointers ie _lvalues_.

Comment: "unless the `char*` is the result of casting a pointer to a properly constructed `MyObject`" => +1. The Standard is very clear that only the 'round trip' form of `reinterpret_cast` between incompatible pointer types has defined results. Anything else is UB and hoping desperately that your compiler does what you think it should. The proper way to convert arbitrary bytes to some object - assuming it's is trivially copyable, as it must be - is to allocate an instance and `memcpy()` from the `char` buffer into it. Heck, good optimisers can render to the same code as a cast, but without invoking UB

Answer (score -1):

I like Jerry Coffin and larsman's answers, depending on wheather the location in question already has a constructed object in it or not.

There is one further wrinkle though. If the type of `MyObject` happens to qualify as a [POD class](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/fpcltf/Pkg/ISOcxx/doc/POD.html), then it might be OK to just use a reintreprent cast on the pointer like larsman suggested, as no constructor is really required for the object.

I say "might" because it is remotely possible that your platform uses different representations for `char *` and class pointers. Most I've used don't do that though.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been a comment on one of those answers? Anyway, address types don't matter: the cast will convert as needed. The issues is whether the Standard allows reinterpreting arbitrary bytes (address-converted) as some object type `T`, possibly with a stricter alignment than `char` that the compiler can't verify. I'm quite convinced it does _not_ allow this - unless the `char *` in question originally came from a valid allocated `T *` - and that anything else is formally UB. See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436092/c-casting-char-to-object#comment65366526_5436137

Comment: (copying comment for posterity) Even if _trivially copyable_ types - the superset of PODs that qualify per the Standard to be copyable to array of `char` & back & keep the same value - don't in reality emit any constructor code, the Standard still demands that such objects have a well-defined lifetime. This presumably means the compiler must see code saying 'Create a `struct T` in this piece of memory', otherwise all bets are off & means it can emit unsafe code or optimise the attempt away. That most compilers allow arbitrary casting, as you very vaguely recommend here, doesn't make it not UB.

Comment: It would have had to be a comment on all three of them (which this software doesn't allow for really), plus I had some additional material addressing the question directly. I'll admit the current standard is much better about this than the pre-C++11 standard I was operating under when I composed this post.